# MySQL | data validation

Tags: mysql, sql, validation, ddl

How can i make it so that with a MySQL column you can only input certain options i.e. 'YES', 'NO'

I know this is possible but i can't find how to do this and searching online hasn't helped!

Thank you,

Comment: Using a before insert trigger.

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way of doing this is probably to define [an enum type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html):

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    my_column ENUM('YES', 'NO')
);
```

Comment: A `tinyint(1)` with a value of `1` or `0` will also work, but which is more optimized?

Comment: you need to use `set sql_mode='STRICT_ALL_TABLES';` then otherwise no error will be raised in case of wrong value